# Postfix time in queue manager very high

Tags: postfix, performance, email-server, email

http://screencast.com/t/7Ok2PwDDj

I have been running Postfix 2.6.6 for the last 5 months. There has not been any server changes and the config allowed me to send 150,000 emails per hour with no problems.

Now, things have slowed down and are progressively getting slower since about a week ago.

The snapshot I linked shows my "delays" and you can see that the "Time in Queue Manager" has gone to 3 and 4 seconds which has choked my mail delivery down to about 20,000 mails per hour vs 150,000.

Does something need to be flushed or reset somewhere? I don't understand why, with no changes, that all of a sudden I begin to get these large delays after working beautifully for several months.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your server ip address in DNSSBL for blacklist and check the /var/log/maillog and look at mail status that mail are getting delivered,bounce,differed or sent according to mai status if it is sent than no problem if it is bounce or differed than this may be the reason that your server has been blocked by receiving mail server's to deliver mails on their user's to stop spam sending.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure that your local DNS server is responding correctly (even for your own domains), or it might just be that google is just throttling you.

Comment: DNS lookups are reported in the "connect setup time" according to the release notes, not the "in queue manager" metric - see also https://serverfault.com/questions/24121/understanding-a-postfix-log-file-entry