# Postfix pipe delayed

Tags: postfix

I am running postfix on a raspberry pi. My outdoor camera is sending an email when it detects any motion. I am piping this email to a script. There is always a delay of 2-3s but the pi is 99% idle. So I assume it is a config issue.

Log:

```
Oct  3 18:07:55 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[11348]: connect from OutdoorCam.fritz.box[192.168.173.39]
Oct  3 18:07:55 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[11348]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from OutdoorCam.fritz.box[192.168.173.39]: <fhem@raspberrypi.local>: Sender address triggers FILTER triggerCamAlert:dummy; from=<fhem@raspberrypi.local> to=<fhem@raspberrypi.local> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>
Oct  3 18:07:55 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[11348]: 38F713FED0: client=OutdoorCam.fritz.box[192.168.173.39]
Oct  3 18:07:55 raspberrypi postfix/cleanup[11351]: 38F713FED0: message-id=<>
Oct  3 18:07:55 raspberrypi postfix/qmgr[24540]: 38F713FED0: from=<fhem@raspberrypi.local>, size=469, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  3 18:07:55 raspberrypi postfix/smtpd[11348]: disconnect from OutdoorCam.fritz.box[192.168.173.39]
Oct  3 18:07:57 raspberrypi postfix/pipe[11352]: 38F713FED0: to=<fhem@raspberrypi>, orig_to=<fhem@raspberrypi.local>, relay=triggerCamAlert, delay=2.5, delays=0.07/0/0/2.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via triggerCamAlert service)
Oct  3 18:07:57 raspberrypi postfix/qmgr[24540]: 38F713FED0: removed
```

master.cf

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

triggerCamAlert unix - n n - - pipe flags=X user=filter argv=/opt/fhem/triggerCamAlert.sh
```

Any idea what could cause this delay?

Any hint is very welcome!

Tobelix

Answer (score 3):

For the discerning reader the information is already in your log file.

You guesstimate of *"a delay of 2-3s"* is in your example is actually spot on with exactly 2.5 seconds:

```
Oct  3 18:07:57 raspberrypi postfix/pipe[11352]: ... delay=2.5, delays=0.07/0/0/2.4 ...
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `delays=a/b/c/d` is actually a breakdown to which part of the SMTP transaction takes how much time as explained in this [Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/24121/37681).

The longest at 2.4 seconds is the message transmission time.

It simply takes a the sender a long time to submit the complete message, there is nothing inherently wrong with your Postfix config that is to blame.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
But everything is happening on localhost. The message size is very small. I can hardly believe that it really takes 2.4s for the message transmission.
If so, is there any part in the config where I could try to reduce that time?